# Company Logo set with schema.org syntax not displayed by google job search

Tags: search, icons

I'm working on a company page that contains job adverts which should be readable by the new google job search. This is done by adding some schema.org-syntax (see below) to each job advert page. Everything works fine, job descriptions, addresses, company names and so forth are displayed just as wanted on the new job-search-display. (if you don't know what I mean: Google, for example, "jobs iam", there will be a blue box amongst the results displaying open jobs from all over the web).

Now, in that blue box each advert is supposed to display the logo of the company offering the job, and I added the code just like it says in the google-how-to ( https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting#guidelines ). But google won't display those icons I specify (checked and re-checked the URLs, they're correct, also the google test tool doesn't complain about my code).

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong here?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "JobPosting",
        "hiringOrganization": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "*** Company Name ***",
            "sameAs": "*** Company URL ***",
            "logo": "https://*** Job Page ***/company-icon.png"
        }, 
etc etc etc
```